# How to check if a div has a liquid / auto height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to check in javascript (or maybe jQuery) if a div has the css property `height:auto`, or maybe check if this div hasn't any height set? But actually the browser act like it keeps calculating the current height of the div and then assign it to that div. So in fact the div always have a height set even if in css we said that div must be in `height:auto`. How can I do this?

Comment: jw under what circumstances you need this functionality? Are you trying to retrieve the height of the element even if the height is set to auto?

Comment: Na it's exactly the opposite. I don't want to retrieve a value I only want to detect (with JS) if a div is liquid or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which I implemented successfully in my jQuery plugin, [ScaleText](https://github.com/morrissinger/scaleText):

```
  function checkAutoHeight(el) {
    // Get the original height of the parent.
    var origHeight = $(el).parent().outerHeight();

    // Create a 1px bump in the size of the element you are checking.
    var tester = $(el).append('<div class="scaleTextHeightCheck" style="display: block; height: 1px; width: 1px; content: \'\';""></div>');

    // Check to see if the parent increased by 1px as a result of the bump.
    var newHeight = $(el).parent().outerHeight();

    // Cleanup.
    $('.scaleTextHeightCheck').detach();

    // Return the result.
    return (origHeight < newHeight);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of one of the following to see if they can help you

```
document.getElementById ( 'divid' ).style.height
$('#divid').css ( 'height' )
$('#divid')[0].style.height
```

Obviously, *divid* is the id of your div

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in IE using the currentStyle attribute

```
var height= document.getElementById('divid').currentStyle.height;
```

Unluckily you can't do it in any other browser (I think it is the only thing I love about IE). Actually you can do it, but not in a direct way.

The way around in other browsers is the following:

first you have to check inline height attribute (it could be a table, which is allowed to use it), then you have to find inline style attribute and check if it has a height defined. Then, you have to iterate through all the styles in your document, and detect the maching one which is more strict, and also check if there is another one less strict but with the !important modifier.

As you can see, it is not an easy process, so the it is possible in other browsers, but not easy. If you are only targeting IE then you are done :-)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this yesterday, but I found a hack that works.

**Plugin**

```
$.fn.isAuto = function(){
    var originalHeight = this.height();
    this.append('<div id="test"></div>');
    var testHeight = originalHeight+500;
    $('#test').css({height: testHeight});
    var newTestHeight = $('#test').height();
    var newHeight = this.height();
    $('#test').remove();
    if(newHeight>originalHeight){
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAnKa/9/) demonstrating the plugin.

Basically, the plugin adds a div inside the original element and gives it a height greater than the original element.  If the original element's new height is greater than original height, the element grew and the height is auto.